# Filebeat kubernetes deployment unable to format json logs into fields

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat

i want to ingested containers json log data using filebeat deployed on kubernetes, i am able to ingest the logs to but i am unable to format the json logs in to fields

following is the logs visible in kibana

[image]

I want to take out the fields from messages above e.g. field for log.level, message, service.name and so on

Following are the filebeat configuration we are using

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
     paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
        - /var/log/containers/*.json
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"


    # To enable hints based autodiscover, remove `filebeat.inputs` configuration and uncomment this:

    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          node: ${NODE_NAME}
          templates:
            - condition:
                contains:
                  kubernetes.container.name: "no-json-logging"
              config:
                - type: container
                  paths:
                    - "/var/log/containers/*-${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log"
           - condition:
                contains:
                  kubernetes.container.name: "json-logging"
              config:
                - type: container
                  paths:
                    - "/var/log/containers/*-${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log"
                  json.keys_under_root: true
                  json.add_error_key: true
                  json.message_key: message


    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:
      - add_host_metadata:

    cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:XX.XX.XX.XX}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9201}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.5.3
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: XX.XX.XX.XX
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9201"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          # If using Red Hat OpenShift uncomment this:
          #privileged: true
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0640
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
      - name: data
        hostPath:
          # When filebeat runs as non-root user, this directory needs to be writable by group (g+w).
          path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: filebeat
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
  namespace: kube-system
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: filebeat
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources:
    - replicasets
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources:
    - jobs
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  # should be the namespace where filebeat is running
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - coordination.k8s.io
    resources:
      - leases
    verbs: ["get", "create", "update"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - kubeadm-config
    verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
---
```

How can i take out the fields from json message?

Comment: Go through the following links for required information:
1) https://discuss.elastic.co/t/parse-json-data-with-filebeat/80008
2) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-json-fields.html

Comment: Hello, i followed the link and tried to follow below option but i didnt fount it is working . will it work for kubernetes filebeat deployment..   i do not find any reference to use filebeat.prospectors: inside kubernetes filebeat configuration

Comment: Refer to the following documents:
1) https://help.sumologic.com/docs/search/search-query-language/parse-operators/parse-json-formatted-logs/ 
2) https://medium.com/@semih.sezer/how-to-send-airflow-logs-to-elasticsearch-using-filebeat-and-logstash-250c074e7575

Comment: Hi @MuraliSankarbanda sorry it seems i had issue with my configuration i reinstalled the filebeat on kubernetes & followed as suggested in second link  it worked fine.   Thank you so much for help.   working solution as followed by link :  https://medium.com/@semih.sezer/how-to-send-airflow-logs-to-elasticsearch-using-filebeat-and-logstash-250c074e7575

Answer (score 1):

The issue is from configuration. One possible work around is reinstalling the filebeat and sending the logs to elastic search.

Follow the content in the blog by
[Semih Sezer](https://medium.com/@semih.sezer/how-to-send-airflow-logs-to-elasticsearch-using-filebeat-and-logstash-250c074e7575) which has the process of sending Airflow logs to elastic search using filebeat.